# STM32 ST-LinkV2 st-flash1.6.1 won't upload - Windows 10

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f4

I am trying to write a binary to a STM32F413ZH Nucleo development board. I am running Windows 10.

I using the bare metal project examples from this [github-page](https://github.com/fcayci/stm32f4-bare-metal). I can succesfully compile any of the example projects but I can't write the binary to the microcontroller.

I am using the makefile which is included in the example projects. To build I write "make" and to write the binary I write "make burn". This gives the following error message:

```
$ make burn
st-flash 1.6.1
2020-10-21T17:06:17 INFO common.c: F1xx Medium-density: 20 KiB SRAM, 64 KiB flash in at least 1 KiB pages.
mmap() size_t overflow for file Debug/dac.bin
2020-10-21T17:06:17 ERROR common.c: map_file() == -1
stlink_fwrite_flash() == -1
make: *** [burn] Error -1
```

Can anyone explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: it tries to flash  `F1xx Medium-density` instead `F4` wrong settings somewhere there. find better examples

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see that it was trying to upload to F1. Thank you. I'll have a look and report back.

Comment: Building and flashing of the examples works well on Mac and Linux I should say. The processor is setup as -mcpu=cortex-m4.